# Removing the intercept term for penalized logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, intercept, regularization

I am working on lasso logistic regression and am trying to remove the intercept term from the penalty function. I have tried to use the mean centering theory but for logistic regression it can not be used.

Any suggestions on how to remove the intercept term?

Comment: Are you using software? Building your own optimizer? Can you paste/sketch what you have done?

Comment: Use software that do not penalize the intercept. One example is `glmnet` (in R.)